# Do I have to book a place for a tent at a campsite in Portugal?

Tags: bookings, camping, portugal

In July I plan to go to Portugal (I plan to spend this time in Faro and vicinity). I want to sleep in a tent at campsites. This will be a small, two-person tent. Do I have to book campsites in advance or can I hope that whenever I come to a campsite there will always be a place to pitch my tent?

Comment: How do you plan to travel? It does make a difference whether you hike or drive. When driving you can easily cover 50 km to find a campsite, hiking 5 km might be the most, and might be too much if you had a long day.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My plans have changed and I will not visit Portugal now. However, I emailed several campgrounds in the vicinity of Faro asking them this question. Two of then (http://camping-armacao-pera.com and https://www.campingalvor.com/) answered - and their answer was that there is no need to make a reservation.

Answer (score 1):

Sure, there are plenty of campings in Algarve.
You can check [here](https://en.camping.info/portugal/algarve/campsites) or [here](http://www.portugal-campings.com/pt/?s=&post_type=listing&et-listing-type=none&et-listing-location=5).

You should at least contact the camping to know it's avalability. That's the best I can say.

Please after you travel tell us here about your experience. Enjoy!